# Antenna Length for Low Frequency Radio Signals - Why so long?

Tags: radio, antenna

I know that when you want to pick up low frequency radio signals, the longer the wavelength, the longer the antenna needs to be. Why is that?

mj

Comment: Basically, because light is really really fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of the vibratory modes on a string clamped at both ends.  When you clamp a length of string at both ends, the allowed vibration patterns all have one thing in common; they go to zero at the ends.

[image]

So, the length of the string determines the natural frequencies of vibration; the longer the string, the lower the fundamental frequency.

Very roughly speaking, an antenna acts similarly.  For example, the current must be zero at the ends of a center-fed dipole antenna in analogy with the clamped ends of the string.

[image]

So, for the antenna to resonate at a lower frequency, it must be longer, just as the string must be.